# Exception is declared but not handled SCJP

Tags: java

```
public class Starter extends Thread{  

    private int x = 2;   

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   

        new Starter().makeItSo();  
    }

    public Starter()
    { 
        x = 5;
        start();
    } 

    public void makeItSo() throws Exception { 
        join(); 
        x = x - 1; 
        System.out.println(x); 
    }

    public void run() { 
        x *= 2; 
    }
}
```

I understand how the code works and the answer is "9". But i have a doubt in Exception concept. As i know `join()` method throws an `Exception` i.e `Interrupted Exception` , so we declared that exception but why we didn't handled that exception in main method?

And suppose if i handled this exception in the same method , where i have declared `join()`. Then what i need to do in `main()` method??

Comment: main(String[] args) **throws Exception**

Comment: To make the compiler happy, any method that can get a "checked" exception must either handle it with try/catch or declare it in the `throws` clause of the method header.  Since `main` declares the exception the compiler should be happy.  (This is entirely unrelated to the question of whether exceptions are being "appropriately" handled -- it's just bookkeeping.)

Answer (score 1):

If join() throws the exception and you handle it in `makeItSo()`, then `makeItSo()` probably won't need to throw it on towards `main()` (or whoever calls `makeItSo()`). More crucially, if this main is your only `main()` method and is not being called from somewhere else, it should not be throwing any exceptions that might be thrown, but handling them in try-catch(-finally) blocks.